# Setting up Gitosis, where to create the repos?

Tags: centos, git

I'm trying to setup Gitosis on CentOS 6.2 but have some doubts/problems about it. I read this docs [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitosis), [here](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:gitosis_management) and [here](http://ao2.it/wiki/How_to_setup_a_GIT_server_with_gitosis_and_gitweb) but it's unclear to me where to configure where repositories are created. My server has a partition /data where I create a directory and called /gitrepos. I want all the repos created under that directory. By default if I run the command:

```
gitosis-init < /home/reynierpm/reynierpm.pub
```

I get this

> Initialized empty Git repository in /root/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/
>
> Reinitialized existing Git repository in /root/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/

And I want this repos created under /data/gitrepos, any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the first sentence of the second link you have posted: "Gitosis stores repositories in the **git** user's home directory."

If you have followed the tutorial from the third link you've posted, you should have created user **git** on your system, and Gitosis should be creating new repositories in the home directory of this user as long as you run `gitosis-init` with the **git** user:

```
sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /home/reynierpm/reynierpm.pub
```

Basically, the answer to your question is: Gitosis creates new repositories in $HOME/repositories.

Comment: Hi @vladimir-blaskov, there is no way to change this?

Comment: You can change to home directory of the **git** user and experiment a bit with the `repositories` configuration option as shown [here](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis/blob/master/example.conf#L7).